# Create an Immutable.js Record from a TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

Say that you are writing a React application with Redux and Immutable.js and have the following representation of our entire state, a list of products.

```
import { Record, List } from 'immutable';

export interface ProductProps {
  something: string;
}

interface IRootState {
  products: List<ProductProps>;
}

export class RootState extends Record({
  products: List<ProductProps>()
}) {
  constructor(props?: IRootState) {
    props ? super(props) : super();
  }
}

export const initialState = new RootState();
```

The class RootState exists to implement `IRootState` as an immutable record with a constructor that populates the newly created object if given data to populate it with.

Now the issue with this implementation is the duplication, the repeat of `{ products: List<ProductProps> }`. Each modification of `IRootState` has to come with the equivalent modification of the `extends Record()` clause, something the developer who inherits this code base may not be aware of.

My question then is simple: Is it possible to parameterize `Record` on `IRootState` instead of the JavaScript Object that it's given in the above example?